# How to see all config options of a jQuery plugin (select2)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, plugins, configuration, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 jQuery plugin (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and it's doing its job, but I would like to know how I can see all the configuration options I can send with it. I mean options like:

```
$("#select2select").select2({
    placeholder: "Selecteer een thema...",
    allowClear: false,
    maximumSelectionSize: 2,
    formatResult: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m;
    }
});
```

This actually applies to all jQuery plugins. I'm using it in an MVC project in Visual Studio and there doens't seem to be autocomplete for external libraries.

So how can I look op all the config options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get this within Visual Studio because the select2 jQuery plugin doesn't have [VSDoc](http://appendto.com/jquery-vsdoc/) within the code's comments.

They do have truly excellent documentation on the plugin's website: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation. Everything under the constructor section should give you what you need.

Comment: Do you by accident know if it's possible to keep the selected items in the list but disabled? Thanks for the link also ;)

Comment: No idea. I've never used that plugin before.